# DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7)

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the sample code of paypal in php from 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

but whenever i am running this sample code i am getting this error.

"DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7)"

I have no clue what's the problem.

Note: I am using local WAMP server for running this sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Set the curl parameters.


 - $ch = curl_init();   
   curl_setopt($ch,   CURLOPT_PROXY, "   http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/";);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,    $API_Endpoint);    
   curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // Turn off the server and peer  //verification(TrustManager Concept).   
   curl_setopt($ch,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);   
   curl_setopt($ch,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);   
   curl_setopt($ch,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//The rest of the code from paypal site
```