# paypal- dodirectpayment failed couldnt connect to host7

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm having a problem with my paypal integration. It was working fine until a few days ago. But now I'm always getting the same error:

**DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7)**

I think I'm getting the same problem as discussed on this post

[DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387431/dodirectpayment-failed-couldnt-connect-to-host7)

But I cannot make the answer working.
it looks that I have to enter this new line:

curl_setopt($ch,   CURLOPT_PROXY, "   http ://username:password @ proxyserver.net:port/";);

and I think I have to enter the right information for the CURLOPT_PROXY, but where can I find this information?

Thank you very much for your help.
Mathias.

Answer (score 0):

You only need CURLOPT_PROXY in case you wanted to access paypal via a proxy.
Remove that proxy line and try again.

Comment: but it's when I don't have it that I'm getting the error:
DoDirectPayment failed: couldn't connect to host(7), so I think I need to access paypal through a proxy.

Comment: Check if you can access the $API_ENDPOINT via your browser

Comment: I think so, I get the reply: ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error after entering: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp